# Content script window.addEventListener(load,function,false) not working in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

i am programming in Chrome extension to create a button control in Gmail page using javascript.After login the Gmail Account,click the compose mail and click anyone place in composemail popup,i have adding one button.And also,click any inbox mail,i have adding one button to the mail content page.its working in window.addEventListener click.

```
window.addEventListener('click', myfunction, false);
```

but not working in load,onload.i already tried the below code.

```
if (window.addEventListener)
    {
        window.addEventListener("load", myfunction, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent)
    {
        window.attachEvent("onload", myfunction);
    }
    else 
    {
        window.onload = myfunction;
    }
```

my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "version": "1.0",


  "permissions": [ "contentSettings", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "windows" ],

  "web_accessible_resources": ["encrypt.png", "decrypt.png" ],

  "background": {
    "page": "Gmail.html"
    },

  "content_scripts": [
    {     

    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "*://mail.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "mailSecurity.js"],
      "css": ["image.css", "inboximage.css"]

    }
]

}
```

Anyone can resolve this?

Thanks
Sanju

Comment: if you are using it in BG script it won't work. That code needs to be in content script. I've just tested it,and it works fine ... function myfunction() {
 alert('click');
}

window.addEventListener('click', myfunction, false);

Comment: it works.But in gmail has provide a link to view full mailcontent in the name of view entire message link.if i have click that link,it will open a new tab and loading.But this load event not identified by the above functions.why?

Comment: It works fine for me. Please post your manifest.json

Comment: @SanjuMonu Did you able to fix the issue. I've similar issue with chrome extension and able to receive message from a newWindow.