# Can't print the innerHTML content throught an extension, but it works in my console

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an extension in Firefox, I'm trying to reading the content using ElementByClassName function. Like this.

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('flip-card-back')[0].innerHTML)
```

this works perfectlly in my console and return the result expected. Nevertheless when I'm implementing this in my extension, this doesn't work.

This is what I tried.

```
console.log('test')
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('flip-card-back')[0].innerHTML)

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var eles = document.getElementsByClassName('flip-card-back')[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(eles);
})
```

The first console is printed correctly, unlike the other ones.

Notice that I've used window event listener function to wait for the DOM to load. But still didn't work. I also printed the HTMLColecction itself, (without tanking the item 0) and it seems to work. What I'm doing wrong?

This is the page I'm trying to take the content from. [here](https://www.scrumpoker-online.org/en/room/459911/scrum-poker)

Thanks!

Comment: May `flip-card-back` class removed of element after load

Comment: The extension probably loads after the page's lifecycle events have already happened.

Comment: @connexo I thought that's why I needed to use `window.addEventListener`, could you guide me to fix it?

Comment: @mortezaataiy But I can see the innerhtml in the console, does it makes sense? I also can see the class throught inspect element, but for some reason when I get the content in the extension is empty :(

Comment: @sharki do second console in the EventListener print innerHTML? So where you can't get innerHTML?

Comment: `when I get the content in the extension is empty` Get us this code that have problem please.

Comment: @mortezaataiy The second code is the extension itself, the first one is what I tried in my console to see that it works, and yeah it works, but for some reason it doesn't in the extension

Comment: @Sharki Maybe `window.addEventListener('load` don't work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158666/content-script-window-addeventlistenerload-function-false-not-working-in-chrom